# MPMoviePlayerController Full Screen Custom Overlay wrong in IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a custom overlay on the video playing with MPMoviePlayerController, on IOS8 is works perfectly, but on IOS7 it gets messed up. I have something like this.

```
UIView * bar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
/*
//add stuff to the view
*/

[window addSubview:bar];
```

The video is in the correct orientation (Landscape on both), just the overlay gets messed up
IOS8
[image: IOS8 Player Visualizations]
IOS7
[image: IOS7 Player Visualizations]